# Unaligned height of html table header

Tags: html, html-table

Why is table header in first (**NUM**) and second column (**DEPARTMENT**) not level with the rest of other header?

[image]

HTML:

```
<table width="100%">

    <thead>
        <tr role="row" bgcolor="#FF5733">

            <th colspan="1" rowspan="3" width="1%">
                <label>NUM.</label>
            </th>
            <th rowspan="3" width="30%">
                <label>DEPARTMENT</label>
            </th>

        </tr>

        <tr role="row" bgcolor="#FF5733">

            <th colspan="2" rowspan="1">
                <label>CAPITAL PROPERTY</label>
            </th>
            <th colspan="2" rowspan="1">
                <label>INVENTORY</label>
            </th>
            <th colspan="2" rowspan="1">
                <label>CAPITAL PROPERTY</label>
            </th>
            <th colspan="2" rowspan="1">
                <label>INVENTORY</label>
            </th>

        </tr>

        <tr role="row" bgcolor="#FF5733">

            <th tabindex="0" colspan="1" rowspan="1" aria-controls="tbl_penerimaan" aria-label="COST: activate to sort column ascending">
                        <label>COST</label>
            </th>
            <th tabindex="0" colspan="1" rowspan="1" aria-controls="tbl_penerimaan" aria-label="QUANTITY: activate to sort column ascending">
                <label>QUANTITY</label>
            </th>
            <th tabindex="0" colspan="1" rowspan="1" aria-controls="tbl_penerimaan" aria-label="COST: activate to sort column ascending">
                <label>COST</label>
            </th>
            <th tabindex="0" colspan="1" rowspan="1" aria-controls="tbl_penerimaan" aria-label="QUANTITY: activate to sort column ascending">
                <label>QUANTITY</label>
            </th>
            <th tabindex="0" colspan="1" rowspan="1" aria-controls="tbl_penerimaan" aria-label="COST: activate to sort column ascending">
                <label>COST</label>
            </th>
            <th tabindex="0" colspan="1" rowspan="1" aria-controls="tbl_penerimaan" aria-label="QUANTITY: activate to sort column ascending">
                <label>QUANTITY</label>
            </th>
            <th tabindex="0" colspan="1" rowspan="1" aria-controls="tbl_penerimaan" aria-label="COST: activate to sort column ascending">
                <label>COST</label>
            </th>
            <th tabindex="0" colspan="1" rowspan="1" aria-controls="tbl_penerimaan" aria-label="QUANTITY: activate to sort column ascending">
                <label>QUANTITY</label>
            </th>

        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr role="row">

            <td>1</td>
            <td>IT Dept.</td>
            <td>0.00</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0.00</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>2,863,184.70</td>
            <td>265</td>
            <td>55,229.00</td>
            <td>89</td>

        </tr>
    </tbody>

    <tfoot>
        <tr bgcolor="#FF5733">

            <td colspan="2" rowspan="1">TOTAL</td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">0.00</td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">0</td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">0.00</td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">0</td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">2,863,184.70</td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">265</td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">55,229.00</td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">89</td>

        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Here is jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/2xasogpq/

As you can see from jsfiddle, there's no external CSS involve. Table header height is uneven on chrome and firefox. Please assist me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you edit your HTML to a minimal example? We only - really - need the 'num','department' and 'capital property' columns to demonstrate the misalignment. Also, you're using `<label>` elements wrong; a `<label>` is used to associate a given text/content with an interactive form element (such as an `<input>`, `<textarea>` etc); your use case is already covered by wrapping the text in a `<th>` element.

Comment: I feel like im missing what your trying to do? this table makes sense to me when i look at it, what should it look like?

Comment: @JLGriffin there's an extra height on `DEPARTMENT` column  next to `CAPITAL PROPERTY` https://i.imgur.com/MpLLcbZ.png The heeader height is not similar.

Comment: OHH check my solution below:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Equally aligned

There's an extra height on DEPARTMENT column when compared to CAPITAL PROPERTY because of making separate tr tag for CAPITAL PROPERTY row.

```html
<table width="100%">

<thead>
    <tr role="row" bgcolor="#FF5733">

        <th colspan="1" rowspan="3" width="1%">
            <label>NUM.</label>
        </th>
        <th rowspan="3" width="30%">
            <label>DEPARTMENT</label>
        </th>

        <th colspan="2" rowspan="1">
            <label>CAPITAL PROPERTY</label>
        </th>
        <th colspan="2" rowspan="1">
            <label>INVENTORY</label>
        </th>
        <th colspan="2" rowspan="1">
            <label>CAPITAL PROPERTY</label>
        </th>
        <th colspan="2" rowspan="1">
            <label>INVENTORY</label>
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row" bgcolor="#FF5733">
        <th tabindex="0" colspan="1" rowspan="1" aria-controls="tbl_penerimaan" aria-label="COST: activate to sort column ascending">
                    <label>COST</label>
        </th>
        <th tabindex="0" colspan="1" rowspan="1" aria-controls="tbl_penerimaan" aria-label="QUANTITY: activate to sort column ascending">
            <label>QUANTITY</label>
        </th>
        <th tabindex="0" colspan="1" rowspan="1" aria-controls="tbl_penerimaan" aria-label="COST: activate to sort column ascending">
            <label>COST</label>
        </th>
        <th tabindex="0" colspan="1" rowspan="1" aria-controls="tbl_penerimaan" aria-label="QUANTITY: activate to sort column ascending">
            <label>QUANTITY</label>
        </th>
        <th tabindex="0" colspan="1" rowspan="1" aria-controls="tbl_penerimaan" aria-label="COST: activate to sort column ascending">
            <label>COST</label>
        </th>
        <th tabindex="0" colspan="1" rowspan="1" aria-controls="tbl_penerimaan" aria-label="QUANTITY: activate to sort column ascending">
            <label>QUANTITY</label>
        </th>
        <th tabindex="0" colspan="1" rowspan="1" aria-controls="tbl_penerimaan" aria-label="COST: activate to sort column ascending">
            <label>COST</label>
        </th>
        <th tabindex="0" colspan="1" rowspan="1" aria-controls="tbl_penerimaan" aria-label="QUANTITY: activate to sort column ascending">
            <label>QUANTITY</label>
        </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr role="row">
        <td>1</td>
        <td>IT Dept.</td>
        <td>0.00</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0.00</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>2,863,184.70</td>
        <td>265</td>
        <td>55,229.00</td>
        <td>89</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
<tfoot>
    <tr bgcolor="#FF5733">
        <td colspan="2" rowspan="1">TOTAL</td>
        <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">0.00</td>
        <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">0</td>
        <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">0.00</td>
        <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">0</td>
        <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">2,863,184.70</td>
        <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">265</td>
        <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">55,229.00</td>
        <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">89</td>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you. This one does worked too and with no extra CSS. I prefer this one. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

The cause is the value of [rowspan](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_rowspan.asp). Since its value is 3 for the **NUM** and **DEPARTMENT** columns it would mean that they would span over three rows. Since that's their size, they misalign your `table`. Just set `rowspan` to 1 for those columns if you want them to be your very first row.

Comment: @sg552 I thought that's your aim. What's your aim, how these two columns should be displayed?

Comment: there's an extra height on `DEPARTMENT` column  next to `CAPITAL PROPERTY` https://i.imgur.com/MpLLcbZ.png The header height is not similar. Why is there extra height on `NUM` and `DEPARTMENT` column?

Comment: Because the width of the th items in the first row in the header are specified. If you remove them, then you will not have extra height in the second row: https://jsfiddle.net/8Lquazcr/

Comment: sorry for any confusion in my explanation. It has been solved. Thank you though for trying to help.

Comment: @sg552 no problem, glad to see you getting past the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is with cell spacing. you'll need to add some css to fix this.

```
table{
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}
td,th{
  border: 2px solid white;
}
```

Fiddle attached: https://jsfiddle.net/webnetvn/4banmrxw/8/

Comment: This does worked! Thank you very much but sorry for any confusion.

Comment: not a problem. its sometimes had to post a small piece of your workflow here. but we got it solved so all is well ::)